# Calculating line length - The difference between lines doesn't seem right

Tags: c#, winforms, math, line

I wrote this so that you click one point on an image and then another point.  The points are added to a list and a line is drawn between each 2 points you make.

I'm also keeping tracking of where the lines are made by "Zones".  The lines length is then calculated using 32nd of an inch and saved.

What I'm noticing is you can make a line on the the photos that may look like this as far as length goes  `---------` and its length between the 2 points maybe `13`.  But then your very next line could look like `---------------------------` and its length is `3`.  And its up and down like this for every line you make.  Large lines showing large, sometimes small lengths and tiny lines sometimes showing small, sometimes large lengths.

I'm not sure what to address.

I'll post everything I think is important to see how things are being done.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        if (p1.X == 0)
        {
            p1.X = e.X;
            p1.Y = e.Y;

            var color = zoneMap1.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
            if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("1");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("2");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 150, 1))
            {
                Zone1.Add("3");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("4");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("5");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("6");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("7");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            p2.X = e.X;
            p2.Y = e.Y;

            p1List.Add(p1);
            p2List.Add(p2);

            Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
            p1.X = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
        }
    }
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (p1List.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < p1List.Count; i++)
        {
            if (p1List.Count != 0 && p2List.Count != 0)
            {
                dist = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(p1List[i].X - p1List[i].Y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2List[i].X - p2List[i].Y, 2)) % 32);
                oracleConnection.Void.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(Zone1[i], dist));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed this.
However its the same problem.  Tiny lines giving me 18, long lines giving me 3.

Example.

Line up top is showing a length of 20 and the tiny line below shows a length of 21.

[image: Example]

```
dist = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p2List[i].X - p1List[i].X), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p2List[i].Y - p1List[i].Y), 2))));
```

Comment: What this group was doing was drawing a line w/ pen and paper.  Someone was then later measuring that line using the 1/32 measurements on her 6” scale.  Looking at all their past measurements its like `2, 7, 2, 5, 4`  And all mine are `20, 25, 18`.  Is there something I need to do to convert so its also doing this measurement as if it was the 1/32 of a ruler?

Answer (score 2):

The distance calculation should combine `X` with `X` and `Y` with `Y`, i.e.,

```
dist = sqrt( pow( p2.X-p1.X, 2 ) + pow( p2.Y-p1.Y, 2 ) )
```

You should also be able to justify why you reduce modulo 32.

Comment: Yep your right, I don't know why I was doing it x with y.  What do you mean justify why?

Comment: @Lee: Your expression there makes no sense, but whoever wrote the code *thought* it made sense.  That thought process is a *justification* for why the code is the way it is.  The justification will be *wrong*, but if we can understand your justification then we can understand why you went wrong and how to help you fix it.

Comment: I think he means, what purpose does it serve for your calculation?  Read about what modulo does and it should be clear why it doesnt belong in this distance calculation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: The department who asked for this measures there lines  in 1/32 of an inch.  When I came to stackoverflow and asked how to do that I was told to use `% 32`.

Comment: `var dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1List[i].X - p2List[i].X, 2) + Math.Pow(p1List[i].Y - p2List[i].Y, 2))`

Comment: @Lee I created my own project with this code and tested it.  It works.   Did you take off the Modulo operator?

Comment: @GantTheWanderer I rewrote it, not sure what was going on but I edited above to show what is now giving me numbers.  However the problem is the same.  If I do it with `p1 - p2 + p1 - p2 or p1-p1 + p2 -p2` I'm still getting large numbers for tiny lines and small numbers for long lines all mixed in.

Comment: Also, what are these lengths measured in.  Like with the example above.  20.  What is that?  20 what?